# Displaying login and registration forms side by side using Materialize.css

Tags: html, css, materialize

I have 2 forms for registration and login which I have created using Materialize.css. But I am trying to display it side by side and if I do it its responsiveness is getting disturbed.

https://jsfiddle.net/samson421/or7mbt3x/

```
     <nav>
     <div class="nav-wrapper light-blue darken-3" >


     <a href="#" class="brand-logo">&nbsp;&nbsp;hello.com</a>
     <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons"></i></a>
    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li><a href="sass.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="badges.html">Our Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="collapsible.html">Login</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
      <li><a href="sass.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="badges.html">Our Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="collapsible.html">login</a></li>
    </ul>


   </div>
   </nav><br><br>

  <div class="indexcon" style="margin-left:80px;width:500px">
   <div class="row">   
    <form class="col s12">
      <div class="row" id="fname">
        <div class="input-field col s4">
            <i class="material-icons prefix"></i>
            <input id="icon_prefix" type="text" class="validate">
            <label for="icon_prefix">First Name</label>
        </div>          
      </div>     

  <div class="row" id="lname">
    <div class="input-field col s4">
      <i class="material-icons prefix"></i>
      <input id="icon_prefix" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="icon_prefix">Last Name</label>
     </div>
   </div>      

 <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s4">
      <i class="material-icons prefix"></i>
      <input id="icon_prefix" type="email" class="validate">
      <label for="icon_prefix">Email ID</label>
    </div>
 </div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s4">
      <i class="material-icons prefix"></i>
      <input id="icon_prefix" type="password" class="validate">
      <label for="icon_prefix">Password</label>
    </div>
</div>


 <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s4">Date of Birth
      <input type="date" class="datepicker">
     </div>
 </div>


 <p>
    <input name="group1" type="radio" id="test1" />
    <label for="test1">Male</label>
 </p>

 <p>
    <input name="group1" type="radio" id="test2" />
    <label for="test2">Female</label>
 </p>


 <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit"   name="action">Register
  <i class="material-icons right"></i>
 </button><br><br>

  </form>    
 </div>
```

```
   <div class="indlog" style="width:400px">
     <div class="row" id="lname">
       <div class="input-field col s4">
        <i class="material-icons prefix"></i>
      <input id="icon_prefix" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="icon_prefix">Username</label>
    </div>

    </div>   

     <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s4">
        <i class="material-icons prefix"></i>
        <input id="icon_prefix" type="password" class="validate">
        <label for="icon_prefix">Password</label>
      </div>

     <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Login
      <i class="material-icons right"></i>
      </button><br><br>
     </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you just have to put both forms into another row divided into 2 columns, like in this example:

```
<div class=" row" >
<form> // form 1
<div class="col s6">
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <input id="password" type="password" class="validate">
      <label for="password">Password</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <input id="email" type="email" class="validate">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
<form> // form 2
 <div class="col s6">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <input id="password" type="password" class="validate">
      <label for="password">Password</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <input id="email" type="email" class="validate">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </form>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the power of the library.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <form id="" action="" method="" role="form" class="col s12">
         <div class="row"
         <div class="input-field col s6">
           <input type="" name="" id="" class="validate" value="">
           <label for=""></label>
         </div>
         <div class="input-field col s6">
            <input type="" name="" id="" class="validate" value="" >
         </div>
   </div> <!-- closes row -->
   <div class="row col s12">
      <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Submit
      <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
     </button>
  </div>
```

And also use the material calendar,  in your fiddle you're omitting.  No need to use custom styling inside html tags.  That is the advantage of the library,  if need to customize elements, use the **laas** features.